# Energy Meter power supply advice/help

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, ac-dc

I've been assigned to start working on a smart energy meter project, it's been like 10 years since I put any work in AC. I would be sincerely grateful for any constructive advice. Now the 3-phase meters I'm been assigned to work on are class 1 smart meters and apparently they need to comply with IEC62053-21 power consumption limits for voltage circuits which are as follows

[image: power su]

Also the since the metrology part/ front end which consists of,

- Current Measurement: Current transformer (isolated from mains, no neutral reference need to be connected).
- Voltage measurements (need to be non-isolated and the neutral needs to be connected to the ground of the system) of course any modem or communication device is to isolated.

The Main SOC (MCU+Metrology) is power hog and it apparently draws around 50 mA alone, the rest of the circuit probably another 20 mA maximum. I've been hinted to study the possibility of using dropper capacitor power supplies+ DC-DC regulators which have high input tolerance (60V) instead of transformer based AC-DC ones. I've been gathering all i can to fully understand the circuit to get 12VDC, seems I'm still going no where.

For now my questions are the following:

1. Which type of power supply type (non-isolated) should I use while designing the power supply (capacitor dropper, etc) 10 VA or 2 W, based on my previous calculations 10VA @ 230V will give about 43 mA which is tiny? I'm confused help?
2. How do I calculate the power efficiency of the dropper capacitor? I'm aware of the Pout/Pin but since this has capacitor the equation is not applicable?

All my findings and work are available here: https://www103.zippyshare.com/v/U7kgRZK8/file.html

Comment: You need to be actively stating what power is needed by your monitor circuits. Then you make the choice. At the moment this is unclear but I suspect 0.6 watts maximum is required (12 volts at 50 mA). Be clearer!

Comment: My apologies, monitoring circuits will take around 100 mA @ 12VDC.

Comment: So, you need a **maximum** continuous power of......?

Comment: The 12V goes to a 12V latching relay ( takes for 20ms ) around 6W but i think this can be managed by a big capacitor somewhere. a 3.3V DC-DC 95% efficiency sources from the 12V rail and the output goes to the main processing unit which consumes 100mA @3.3V which is  0.33W.

Comment: So, if you used a storage capacitor to deliver the 6 watts over 20 ms, what would be the average power needed to replenish the capacitor charge over the minimum time period between activations of the latching relay. Power Integrations are possibly going to be a source of the power supply circuit. I've seen them used in electricity/smart meters. Take a look at the power circuit in this: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/DRM143.pdf and although it's only 4 watts or so it may do the job with some mods (page 8 in yellow box).

Comment: Looks very promising , though since the meter is 3 phase and requires all three lines to be connected in parallel ( redundancy measures ). I'm afraid this might not work with all 3 lines joined together, kindly share your thoughts on this point

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but you need to consider safety unless the system is completely enclosed (no IO) you need to have isolation of some sort.

Comment: @Damien The meter is fully enclosed , any communication interface will be isolated from the mains ofcourse

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for pointing out a type of power supply, i've searched for a 3-phase meter configuration and this is what i've come up with https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/DRM147.pdf (page 9) .

Comment: Yes, using three diodes is sensible to make all three phases contribute to power.

Comment: "  it's only 4 watts or so it may do the job with some mods " did i get that right, that the mod referred to is to connect a super cap or a battery to aid in the 6W delivery ?. Last question , Is there a way to simulate this circuit ? i'm assuming neither LTSpice nor TINA will have this IC ?